# PCEP error RP object missing

Tags: opendaylight

Note: this editor is messing up the text alignment of the wireshark capture

Cisco IOS XR router send a PCEP request to ODL PCE for path computation and gets a PCEP Error message type 6 value 1: Mandatory object missing, RP Object missing.

Wireshark shows that the PCEP client (the router) sends the PCE request message with the RP object hence the error seems contradictory. Although we do notice that the RP object is setting the OF flag (Objetive Flag) which is not defined in RFC 5440, and was only introduced in RFC 5541 so could be that ODL rejects this PCEP request due to unsopported flag.

However, when using a Cisco PCE controller (XTC), it works fine.

Any idea what could be causing the ODL controller to reject this PCE Request message and if the issue if the OF flag, how to configure the ODL server to support it.... 
Below is the wirekshare capture of this PCE request and reply message: PCE request message from PCC (Cisco Router) to PCE (ODL Beryllium)

1st packet is from PCC (Cisco Router) to ODL PCE, this is the PCE Request

```
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
1       2017-11-09 15:39:54.619757083 10.92.224.112         10.93.1.11            PCEP     162    Path Computation Request (PCReq)

Frame 1: 162 bytes on wire (1296 bits), 162 bytes captured (1296 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Cisco_66:aa:3d (70:e4:22:66:aa:3d), Dst: Dell_c9:03:6a (ec:f4:bb:c9:03:6a)
802.1Q Virtual LAN, PRI: 0, CFI: 0, ID: 10
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.92.224.112, Dst: 10.93.1.11
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 17568, Dst Port: 4189, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 104
    Source Port: 17568
    Destination Port: 4189
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 104]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 105    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
    Window size value: 63986
    [Calculated window size: 63986]
    [Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)]
    Checksum: 0x7acc [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
    [PDU Size: 104]
Path Computation Element communication Protocol
    Path Computation Request (PCReq) Header
    RP object
        Object Class: RP OBJECT (2)
        0001 .... = RP Object-Type: Request Parameters (1)
        Flags
        Object Length: 20
        Reserved: 0x00
        Flags: 0x000080
            0000 0000 0... .... .... .... = Reserved Flags: Not set
            .... .... .0.. .... .... .... = (C) Core-tree computation: Not set
            .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = (F) Fragmentation: Not set
            .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = (N) P2MP: Not set
            .... .... .... 0... .... .... = (E) ERO-compression: Not set
            .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = (M) Make-before-break: Not set
            .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = (D) Report the request order: Not set
            .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = (P) Path Key: Not set
            .... .... .... .... 1... .... = (S) Supply OF on response: Set
            .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = (V) VSPT: Not set
            .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = (L) Strict/Loose: Not set
            .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = (B) Bi-directional: Not set
            .... .... .... .... .... 0... = (R) Reoptimization: Not set
            .... .... .... .... .... .000 = (PRI) Priority: Off
        Requested ID Number: 0x0000000c
        PATH-SETUP-TYPE
            Type: PATH-SETUP-TYPE (28)
            Length: 4
            Reserved: 0x000000
            Path Setup Type: Path is setup using Segment Routing (1)
    END-POINT object
    LSP object
    LSPA object
    BANDWIDTH object
    METRIC object
```

2nd packet is the PCE reply from ODL PCE to PCC (Cisco router):

```
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
2       2017-11-09 15:39:54.622698028 10.93.1.11            10.92.224.112         PCEP     66     Error (PCErr)

Frame 2: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_c9:03:6a (ec:f4:bb:c9:03:6a), Dst: Cisco_66:aa:3d (70:e4:22:66:aa:3d)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.93.1.11, Dst: 10.92.224.112
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4189, Dst Port: 17568, Seq: 1, Ack: 105, Len: 12
    Source Port: 4189
    Destination Port: 17568
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 12]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 13    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 105    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
    Window size value: 229
    [Calculated window size: 229]
    [Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)]
    Checksum: 0x7621 [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
    [PDU Size: 12]
Path Computation Element communication Protocol
    Error (PCErr) Header
    ERROR object
        Object Class: PCEP ERROR OBJECT (13)
        0001 .... = PCEP-ERROR Object-Type: PCEP Error (1)
        Flags
        Object Length: 8
        Reserved: 0x00
        Flags: 0x00
        Error-Type: Mandatory Object Missing (6)
        Error-Value: RP object missing (1)
```

Comment: could the OF flag in the RP object be the issue?

Comment: On the ODL PCE controller, tried Berrylium and Carbon.
the PCC is running IOS XR 6.2.2